# yield WaitForSeconds throwing errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm just attempting to write a script for a game that is meant to destroy the object its attached to after 4 seconds.

But there's a problem with my code that I cant seem to fix. I would really appreciate it if someone could help.

Here's what I have:

```
public class laserDestroy : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Start ()
    {
        run();
    }

    IEnumerator run()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
        Destroy(this.GameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you described what your problem actually is.

Comment: Well it was originally a heap of different errors, now its just saying: "Assets/_scripts/laserDestroy.cs(13,25): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `new'"

Hmmmm

Answer (score 1):

To start a coroutine, use the [`StartCoroutine`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) function:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(Run());
    // Alternatively: StartCoroutine("Run")
}

IEnumerator Run()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
    // Code
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so here's what I have now:

void Start () {
  StartCoroutine(Run());
 }

  IEnumerator Run()
 {
  yield new WaitForSeconds(4);
  Destroy(this.GameObject);
 }

But for some reason its saying: Assets/_scripts/laserDestroy.cs(13,25): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `new'

Comment: Right, sorry. It acutally needs to be `yield return new WaitForSeconds(4)`. I edited my answer.